# Install Zenko Cloud Server on ubuntu 20.04 for development purpose

Tags: amazon-s3, object-storage, fileserver, cloud-object-storage

For a couple of days, I have been trying to install the **Zenko cloud server** for development purposes on my ubuntu 20.04 machine. I am new to Docker and definitely not very much comfortable with Kubernetes and Helm. I am trying to follow [this](https://zenko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/index.html) instruction. During the installation stage when I am trying to follow [this link](https://github.com/Scality/Zenko/releases), I am getting this error

> Error: validation failed: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "PodSecurityPolicy" in version "policy/v1beta1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1beta1"]

while executing this command.

> helm install
> https://github.com/scality/Zenko/releases/download/1.2.5/zenko-1.2.5.tgz

I have also tried [this link](https://www.zenko.io/blog/deploy-zenko-locally-with-minikube/) to install Zenko. I have successfully cloned Zenko from the git repository.

> git clone https://github.com/scality/Zenko.git

But while executing **cd ./zenko/charts**, I am getting this error.

> bash: cd: ./zenko/charts: No such file or directory

I have installed Minkube by following [this link](https://www.linuxtechi.com/how-to-install-minikube-on-ubuntu/) and also installed Helm2 by following [this link](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#from-apt-debian-ubuntu). Also, I have tried to follow [this Zenko documentation](https://s3-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GETTING_STARTED.html#installation) but did not quite understand it.

My current goal is to install the Zenko cloud server and upload files to Amazon S3 and also to my local directory where both can be managed via Zenko according to their documentation.

It will be very helpful if someone shows me some way to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.